# Find the limit $\lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (e^{x^2}-e^{x})=~?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Find $$\lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (e^{x^2}-e^{x})$$

Is this an okay way to find the answer? I get it's a bit on the pedantic side, but I would like to make sure I'm going about this the right way.

$$ = \lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (e^x(e^{x^2-x} - 1)$$

$$ = \lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (e^x) \cdot \lim \limits_{x\to\infty}(e^{x^2-x} - 1))$$

$$ = \lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (e^x) \cdot (\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}(e^{x^2-x}) +  \lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (-1))$$

$$ \lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (e^x) = \infty $$

$$ \lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (-1) = -1 $$

Let $u = x^2-x$

$$ \lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (x^2-x) = \infty $$

$$ \lim \limits_{u\to\infty} (e^u) = \infty $$

$$\lim \limits_{x\to\infty}(e^{x^2-x}) = \infty$$

So, $$\lim \limits_{x\to\infty} (e^{x^2}-e^{x}) =  '' \infty \cdot (\infty - 1) '' = \infty$$

Comment: Instead of factor $e^x$, you should factor $e^{x^2}$ out for an immediate result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be rigorous, you should prove the limit formally: show that for every $N$, there exists an $x_N$ with $e^{x^2}-e^x \geq N$ for every $x \geq x_N$.

It shouldn't be hard to cook up a very loose such $x_N$ by taking advantage of the factoring you found and the monotonicity of $\exp$.

If you are OK with an informal argument, I would stop after your first step,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{x^2}-e^x = \lim_{x\to\infty} e^x\left(e^{x^2-x}-1\right)$$
since at this point it's obvious both factors in the product will diverge to infinity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had to think about why it's obvious to you that $\lim_{x\to\infty}(e^{x^2-x})$ diverges to infinity, but I'm assuming it's because the $x^2$ term will grow faster than the $x$ term. Seems like a good idea to keep the growth of different functions in mind when doing these types of problems. 

I would like to be able to prove this limit formally, but I'm not too confident with those types of questions yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a one-sided version of the squeeze theorem whose proof follows almost immediately from definitions:

> If there is a number $M$ satisfying $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x \ge M$ and $g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, then $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ too.

Since the exponential function is increasing you have
$$ x \ge 2 \implies e^{x^2} \ge e^{2x} = e^x e^x \ge 2 e^x \implies e^{x^2} - e^x \ge e^x.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $e^x=t$, so $t=\ln x$, and $e^{x^2}=(e^x)^x=t^x=t^{\ln t}$

$$L=\lim \limits_{t\to\infty}(t^{\ln t}-t)$$

Since $t\to \infty$, in particular, $t\ge2$

$$t^{\ln t}-t\ge t^2-t\ge t$$

therefore,

$$L=\lim \limits_{t\to\infty}(t^{\ln t}-t)\ge \lim \limits_{t\to\infty}~t=\infty$$